# Biholomorphic but not isomorphic complex affine surfaces?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are smooth affine surfaces over $\mathbb C$. Suppose there is a biholomorphism $f: X\to Y$. Does it follow that $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic as affine surfaces (i.e. there exists an algebraic isomorphism $g: X\to Y$)?

What if we additionally know that $X$ and $Y$ are rational surfaces?

Comment: I think that if $E$ is an elliptic curve, then $H^1(E,C)/H^1(E,Z)$ is isomorphic to $C^{*}\times C^{*}$ biolomorphically. On the other hand, I think that the former is an $\mathbb{A}^{1}$ bundle over $E$ by going modulo $H^0(E,\Omega^1_E)$. Will write it up in detail later if no one else does!

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know the answer when $X=\mathbf{C}^2$?

Comment: Thanks for the question! I don't know the answer for $X=\mathbb C^2$. In fact, I am especially interested in the case when $X$ and $Y$ are rational surfaces

Comment: Kapil, thank you for your nice comment. I agree indeed that if you quotient $\mathbb C^2$ by a free abelian group $\Gamma=\langle v_1, v_2\rangle$, where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are not proportional, you get something biholomorphic to $\mathbb C^*\times \mathbb C^*$. But how do you see that $H^1(E,\mathbb C)/H^1(E,\mathbb Z)$ has a natural structure of an affine surface?

Comment: @YCor, CP Ramanujam’s theorem (Annals, 1971) characterizing $\mathbb{C}^2$ topologically implies that a smooth complex affine surface just homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2$ is algebraically isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2$, so in the present case $Y\cong \mathbb{C}^2$. Unfortunately this is not a very easy answer (the easily stated question somehow makes one feel it is quickly within reach).

Comment: Alok Maharana also pointed out to me independently that [an earlier answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/132337/124862) referenced Corollary 4 in a [paper by Freudenberg and Moser-Jauslin](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00209-003-0572-5.pdf) which gives examples as required by OP. Jason Starr's example is much easier!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\overline{C}$ be a complex projective curve of genus $g>0$.  Let $C\subset \overline{C}$ be the open affine complement of one (closed) point $p$.  The composition $\text{Pic}^0(\overline{C})\to \text{Pic}(\overline{C})\to \text{Pic}(C)$ is an isomorphism.  Let $L$ be any nontrivial (geometric) rank $1$ vector bundle over $C$.  This is affine, since $C$ is affine and the projection morphism from $L$ to $C$ is affine.  This projection morphism equals the image of the Albanese morphism of $L$ (this is a birational invariant for complex projective manifolds, thus extends unambiguously to complex quasi-projective manifolds).  The relative tangent bundle of this projection morphism is the pullback from $C$ of a unique invertible sheaf, namely the invertible sheaf associated to $L$.  Thus, the relative tangent bundle of the Albanese morphism is not trivial.  Hence $L$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1\times C$.  Yet the underlying complex manifolds are biholomorphic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer Jason! Do I understand correctly that $L$ and $\mathbb A^1\times C$ are biholomorphic because the line bundle $L$ has a nowhere vanishing, albeit non-algebraic section? Also, I wonder, what would be your guess concerning the case when $X$ and $Y$ are both rational surfaces? Should one expect to be able to find a counter-example in this case as well?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Alternatively, since $C$ is Stein, all topologically trivial holomorphic principal bundles are holomorphically trivial by Grauert-Oka.

Answer (score 3):

*Update*: Note that this fails to provide the required example since the second algebraic structure is *not* affine as desired. However, I am not deleting this answer as yet.

The moduli of flat line bundles over a curve $X$ of genus $g$ is parametrized holomorphically by $\left(\mathbb{C}^*\right)^{2g}$. This uses the topological description of such a line bundle in terms trivialisation on the universal cover. This yields *one* algebraic structure given by $(\mathbb{G}_m)^{2g}$. In particular, this has no morphisms to an Abelian variety.

On the other hand, a line bundle with a flat connection has degree 0. Different flat connections on a line bundle differ by a holomorphic $1$-form on $X$. This shows that the *algebraic* moduli space of flat connections on a line bundle over $X$ is an affine space torsor $T$ for $H^0(X,\Omega^1_X)$ over $\mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$. In other words, $T\to \mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$ is a bundle of $\mathbb{A}^g$'s.

Thus $T$ and $(\mathbb{G}_m)^{2g}$ are two different algebraic structures (since one maps to $\mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$ and the other does not) for the same underlying holomorphic manifold of dimension $2g$. The original question (for surfaces) is answered by taking $g=1$.

@aglearner has asked how we see that there is an algebraic moduli space for flat connections of a fixed dimension $r$ over a smooth projective variety $X$. The most comprehensive reference is the work of Simpson [here](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1994__79__47_0.pdf) and [here](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1994__80__5_0.pdf). However, there ought to be easier to read explanations when $X$ is a curve and $r$ is 1, but I could not find them!

Comment: Dear Kapil, thank you for writing up details for this nice example! Note though that in my question *both* $X$ and $Y$ are affine surfaces. Certainly $\mathbb C^*\times \mathbb C^*$ is affine. But how do you prove that the algebraic moduli space of flat connections on a line bundle over $E$ is an affine surface? I.e why your $Y$ is affine?

Comment: @aglearner I believe $Y$ is not affine (giving an example of a non-affine algebraic stein manifold). See e.g. Remark 7.6 in this paper of Neeman https://www.jstor.org/stable/2007052

Comment: I missed the point about the need for the variety $Y$ to be affine!

Comment: The example for $g=1$ is also explained in an older [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/657/124862) in a different and perhaps easier way.